# How to fill a column of one dataframe, conditionally bound to two columns of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My two dataframes:

```
wetter
Out[223]: 
       level_0               index  TEMPERATURE:TOTAL  SLP HOUR   Time
0            0 2018-01-01 00:00:00                9.8  NaN   00  00:00
1            1 2018-01-01 01:00:00                9.8  NaN   01  01:00
2            2 2018-01-01 02:00:00                9.2  NaN   02  02:00
3            3 2018-01-01 03:00:00                8.4  NaN   03  03:00
4            4 2018-01-01 04:00:00                8.5  NaN   04  04:00
       ...                 ...                ...  ...  ...    ...
49034    49034 2018-12-31 22:40:00                8.5  NaN   22  22:40
49035    49035 2018-12-31 22:45:00                8.4  NaN   22  22:45
49036    49036 2018-12-31 22:50:00                8.4  NaN   22  22:50
49037    49037 2018-12-31 22:55:00                8.4  NaN   22  22:55
49038    49038 2018-12-31 23:00:00                8.4  NaN   23  23:00

[49039 rows x 6 columns]

df
Out[224]: 
0    Time          -14          -13  ...           17           18    NaN
1   00:00  1,256326635  1,218256131  ...  0,080348715  0,040194189  00:15
2   00:15  1,256564788  1,218487067  ...  0,080254367  0,039517006  00:30
3   00:30  1,260350982  1,222158528  ...  0,080219518  0,039054261  00:45
4   00:45  1,259306606  1,221145800  ...  0,080758578  0,039176953  01:00
5   01:00  1,258521518  1,220384502  ...  0,080444585  0,038164953  01:15
..    ...          ...          ...  ...          ...          ...    ...
92  22:45  1,253545107  1,215558891  ...  0,080164570  0,042697436  23:00
93  23:00  1,241253483  1,203639741  ...  0,078395829  0,039685235  23:15
94  23:15  1,242890274  1,205226933  ...  0,078801415  0,039170364  23:30
95  23:30  1,240459118  1,202869448  ...  0,079511294  0,039013684  23:45
96  23:45  1,236228281  1,198766818  ...  0,079186806  0,037570494  00:00

[96 rows x 35 columns]
```

I want to fill the `SLP` column of `wetter` based on `TEMPERATURE:TOTAL` and `Time`.
For this I want to look at the `df` dataframe and fill SLP depending on the columns of `df`, where the headers are temperatures.

So for the first `TEMPERATURE:TOTAL` of `9.8` at `00:00`, `SLP` should be filled with the value of the column that is simply called `9` in row 00:00 of `Time`

I have tried to do this, which is why i also created the Time columns but I am stuck. I thought of some nested loops but knowing a bit of pandas I guess there is probably a two-liner solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

This is me simulating your dataframes (you are free to skip this step) - next time please provide them.

```
wetter = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame()
wetter['TEMPERATURE:TOTAL'] = np.random.rand(10) * 10
wetter['SLP'] = np.nan * 10
wetter['Time'] = pd.date_range("00:00", periods=10, freq="H")
df['Time'] = pd.date_range("00:00", periods=10, freq="15T")
for i in range(-14, 18):
    df[i] = np.random.rand(10)
```

Preprocess:

```
wetter['temp'] = np.floor(wetter['TEMPERATURE:TOTAL'])
wetter = wetter.astype({'temp': 'int'})

wetter.set_index('Time')
df.set_index('Time')
df = df.reset_index()

value_vars_ = list(range(-14, 18))
df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Time', value_vars=value_vars_, var_name='temp', value_name="SLP")
```

Left-join two dataframes on `Time` and `temp`:

```
final = pd.merge(wetter.drop('SLP', axis=1), df_long, how="left", on=["Time", "temp"])
```

Comment: thanks a bunch! Impressive how its a one liner in the end